# Set values to ini File (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need to set values to an ini File, I try to search how to do it but I can't find an answer, the ini File is like:

```
[mysqld]

port=${one.port}
```

I wan to tho similar to:

```
[mysqld]

port=EditPort.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `SetIniString` Function**

From Inno Setup Help,

> `SetIniString` writes a string to an INI file.

You can use it like

```
SetIniString('mysqld', 'port', EditPort.Text, ExpandConstant('<< PATH TO YOUR .INI FILE >>'))
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you! :-)